# How to convert UIScrollView to image?

Tags: iphone

I have a scrollview, frame size is 480x265 and content size is 1800x600.

I have a lot of UIView added as a subview to this scrollview.

May I know how should I be able to convert this scrollview to an image?

Many thanks for any comments/help in advance!

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3539717/getting-a-screenshot-of-a-uiscrollview-including-offscreen-parts

Answer (score 3):

```
- (void)submitClicked
{
     UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(scrollView.contentSize);

     CGPoint savedContentOffset = scrollView.contentOffset;
     CGRect savedFrame = scrollView.frame;

     scrollView.contentOffset = CGPointZero;
     scrollView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, scrollView.contentSize.width,  scrollView.contentSize.height);
     [scrollView.layer renderInContext: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];     
     UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

     scrollView.contentOffset = savedContentOffset;
     scrollView.frame = savedFrame;

     UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
}
```

Comment: this will work great for you because i also suffer form this problem TAUHEED AHMD