# How to make an image with the contents of a UIScrollView?

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview, uiimage

I have a UIScrollView that changes in height as items are added to it. I want to be able to make an image that is as tall as the scrollview at the time and contains its contents. All I have been able to find online is something that gets me an image of what is currently on the screen.

Has anyone tackled this problem before? I'm looking for either a snapshot of the UIScrollView, or a tall image that I can add snapshots to to build the image.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3539717/getting-a-screenshot-of-a-uiscrollview-including-offscreen-parts)

It does what you want.

Comment: Thankyou! It looked burry on the simulator but appears to have worked fine on the phone. Much appreciated!