# Create bitmap of UITextView's entire content

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I'm trying to get a bitmap of a UITextView's content. I'm able to get a bitmap of the UITextView's content that is currently on the screen with:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(myTextView.bounds.size);
[myTextView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *resultingImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
myImageView.image=resultingImage;

UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

But I want a bitmap of ALL the content, not just the content visible on the screen. Is this possible? Note that I don't want only the text of the UITextView, I want a bitmap of the content itself. I searched around and found how do do this in Android, with getDrawingCache, but couldn't find anything for objective c.

Comment: take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3539717/getting-a-screenshot-of-a-uiscrollview-including-offscreen-parts/3539944#3539944

Comment: You're welcome...be aware that if you have an huge uiview(like a long tableview) to render, the method take much time to be executed.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to make a copy of the `UITextView` and then resize the copy to it's content size (as long as the content size is bigger than the frame size).

In Swift it looks like this:

```
func imageFromTextView(textView: UITextView) -> UIImage {

    // Make a copy of the textView first so that it can be resized 
    // without affecting the original.
    let textViewCopy = UITextView(frame: textView.frame)
    textViewCopy.attributedText = textView.attributedText

    // resize if the contentView is larger than the frame
    if textViewCopy.contentSize.height > textViewCopy.frame.height {
        textViewCopy.frame = CGRect(origin: CGPointZero, size: textViewCopy.contentSize)
    }

    // draw the text view to an image
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(textViewCopy.bounds.size, false, UIScreen.mainScreen().scale)
    textViewCopy.drawViewHierarchyInRect(textViewCopy.bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true)
    let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    return image
}
```

This allows you to get an image of all of the content, even the part that in not visible without scrolling.

**Notes**

- My somewhat more general answer is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37054129/3681880).
- The `textViewCopy` is only a copy of the frame and the attributed text. That should be enough to get a full image. However, if for some reason a more exact copy is needed, then one could do the following: ([explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37050633/3681880))

  ```
  let tempArchive = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(textView)
  let textViewCopy = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithData(tempArchive) as! UITextView
  ```