# Calling into jEdit to get a bitmap of the rendered text

Tags: java, swing, jedit

In Swift, it is possible to get the bitmap of generated graphical content:

[Create bitmap of UITextView's entire content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7787027/create-bitmap-of-uitextviews-entire-content)

I would like to have this for the jEdit text area. How could I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the following BeanShell script you can save a PNG of the jEdit text area:

```java
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

img = new BufferedImage(textArea.getWidth(), textArea.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
g = img.getGraphics();
textArea.paint(g);
g.dispose();
ImageIO.write(img, "png", new File(".../textArea.png"));
```

You can save that as action and map it to some shortcut, even adding a dialog that asks for the location where to save the image to.

You can also save it as a file somewhere and then invoke it from outside using `jedit -run=path/to/snapshot-textArea.bsh` to record the currently active text area.

You can do the same with any Swing component, not just with the text area.