# Invalid context when creating UIImageView

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uiimage, cgcontext

I have an error when I tried to create a UIImageView.
Look at this code :

```
UIImage* backgroundPanel = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"loginPanelBackground.png"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(90, 0, 149, 416)];

self.connexionBackgroundImgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:backgroundPanel];
self.connexionBackgroundImgView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 416, 390); // THIS LINE PROVOC THE INVALID CONTEXT
[self.connexionView insertSubview:self.connexionBackgroundImgView aboveSubview:self.connexionToCreationCompteView];
```

It throws this error in the log :

```
<Error>: CGContextSaveGState: invalid context 0x0
<Error>: CGContextSetBlendMode: invalid context 0x0
<Error>: CGContextSetAlpha: invalid context 0x0
<Error>: CGContextTranslateCTM: invalid context 0x0
<Error>: CGContextScaleCTM: invalid context 0x0
<Error>: CGContextGetCTM: invalid context 0x0
<Error>: CGContextSaveGState: invalid context 0x0
<Error>: CGContextClipToRect: invalid context 0x0
<Error>: CGContextDrawTiledImage: invalid context 0x0
<Error>: CGContextRestoreGState: invalid context 0x0
<Error>: CGContextGetCTM: invalid context 0x0
<Error>: CGContextSaveGState: invalid context 0x0
<Error>: CGContextClipToRect: invalid context 0x0
<Error>: CGContextDrawTiledImage: invalid context 0x0
<Error>: CGContextRestoreGState: invalid context 0x0
<Error>: CGContextGetCTM: invalid context 0x0
<Error>: CGContextSaveGState: invalid context 0x0
<Error>: CGContextClipToRect: invalid context 0x0
<Error>: CGContextDrawTiledImage: invalid context 0x0
<Error>: CGContextRestoreGState: invalid context 0x0
<Error>: CGContextRestoreGState: invalid context 0x0
```

I had this error only on the iPad, not with the Simulator, I don't understand.. :/

Comment: Are you using any custom drawing code? like by using CGContext and all?

Comment: Also try changing self.connexionBackgroundImgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 416, 390)];
[self.connexionBackgroundImgView setImage:backgroundPanel]; Actually it shouldnt make much difference. But still you can try.

Comment: Are you using any custom drawing? implementing CGContext somewhere?

Comment: See the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10695258/how-do-i-capture-uiimage-of-complete-contents-of-uitableview-uiscrollview-and

Comment: Thanks eliajf, can you post your comment as an answer. Then, I'll accept it as the right one !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> See the answer here : [How do I capture UIImage of complete contents of UITableView / UIScrollView and make it work on an ios device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10695258/how-do-i-capture-uiimage-of-complete-contents-of-uitableview-uiscrollview-and)

Thanks eliajf !

Answer (score 40):

I had this problem until I found out that my cap inset argument to resizableImageWithCapInsets: was wrong — it didn't leave any un-capped area at all (you need at least 1x1 pixel not covered by a cap). So make sure that:

*(insets.left + insets.right) < width*

and

*(insets.top + insets.bottom) < height*

Comment: This is exactly my case! I'm using resizableImageWithCapInsets and frame is smaller than cap insets, so it throws this warning...

Comment: Great tip, I searched for a long time before finding this :-)

Answer (score 0):

The Simulator is case-insensitive. The device is case-sensitive. The png is named correctly? Maybe it is 'Login' with a capital L.

Comment: The image is displayed correctly both on Simulator and iPad. The log changes nothing but I want to know why I have this error :/

Answer (score 0):

I still can't comment due to low rep. However I'd like to add to neon1's answer which helped me a lot.

You also need to make sure that all of the insets are greater than zero.

*insets.left > 0*

*insets.top > 0*

*insets.right > 0*

*insets.bottom > 0*