# UIButton setImage vs setBackgroundImage with resizable images

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, uibutton, core-graphics

I'm trying to use a resizable image as a button background.

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"btn_prev_secondary"];
UIEdgeInsets edgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(30.0f, 25.0f, 29.0f, 9.0f);
UIImage *resizeableImage = [image resizableImageWithCapInsets:edgeInsets];

// What I'd like to do:
[self.backButton setBackgroundImage:resizeableImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];

// This works (but doesn't do what I want)
// [self.backButton setImage:resizeableImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];

// Also works (also doesn't do what I want)
// [self.backButton setImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

When I run this code, my button background is set properly, but I get all kinds of log errors:

```
Aug 13 17:05:25 MyApp <Error>: CGContextSaveGState: invalid context 0x0
Aug 13 17:05:25 MyApp <Error>: CGContextSetBlendMode: invalid context 0x0
Aug 13 17:05:25 MyApp <Error>: CGContextSetAlpha: invalid context 0x0
Aug 13 17:05:25 MyApp <Error>: CGContextTranslateCTM: invalid context 0x0
Aug 13 17:05:25 MyApp <Error>: CGContextScaleCTM: invalid context 0x0
Aug 13 17:05:25 MyApp <Error>: CGContextGetCTM: invalid context 0x0
Aug 13 17:05:25 MyApp <Error>: CGContextSaveGState: invalid context 0x0
Aug 13 17:05:25 MyApp <Error>: CGContextClipToRect: invalid context 0x0
Aug 13 17:05:25 MyApp <Error>: CGContextDrawTiledImage: invalid context 0x0
Aug 13 17:05:25 MyApp <Error>: CGContextRestoreGState: invalid context 0x0
Aug 13 17:05:25 MyApp <Error>: CGContextGetCTM: invalid context 0x0
Aug 13 17:05:25 MyApp <Error>: CGContextSaveGState: invalid context 0x0
Aug 13 17:05:25 MyApp <Error>: CGContextClipToRect: invalid context 0x0
Aug 13 17:05:25 MyApp <Error>: CGContextDrawTiledImage: invalid context 0x0
Aug 13 17:05:25 MyApp <Error>: CGContextRestoreGState: invalid context 0x0
Aug 13 17:05:25 MyApp <Error>: CGContextGetCTM: invalid context 0x0
Aug 13 17:05:25 MyApp <Error>: CGContextSaveGState: invalid context 0x0
Aug 13 17:05:25 MyApp <Error>: CGContextClipToRect: invalid context 0x0
Aug 13 17:05:25 MyApp <Error>: CGContextDrawTiledImage: invalid context 0x0
Aug 13 17:05:25 MyApp <Error>: CGContextRestoreGState: invalid context 0x0
Aug 13 17:05:25 MyApp <Error>: CGContextGetCTM: invalid context 0x0
Aug 13 17:05:25 MyApp <Error>: CGContextSaveGState: invalid context 0x0
Aug 13 17:05:25 MyApp <Error>: CGContextClipToRect: invalid context 0x0
Aug 13 17:05:25 MyApp <Error>: CGContextDrawTiledImage: invalid context 0x0
Aug 13 17:05:25 MyApp <Error>: CGContextRestoreGState: invalid context 0x0
Aug 13 17:05:25 MyApp <Error>: CGContextGetCTM: invalid context 0x0
Aug 13 17:05:25 MyApp <Error>: CGContextSaveGState: invalid context 0x0
Aug 13 17:05:25 MyApp <Error>: CGContextClipToRect: invalid context 0x0
Aug 13 17:05:25 MyApp <Error>: CGContextDrawTiledImage: invalid context 0x0
Aug 13 17:05:25 MyApp <Error>: CGContextRestoreGState: invalid context 0x0
Aug 13 17:05:25 MyApp <Error>: CGContextGetCTM: invalid context 0x0
Aug 13 17:05:25 MyApp <Error>: CGContextSaveGState: invalid context 0x0
Aug 13 17:05:25 MyApp <Error>: CGContextClipToRect: invalid context 0x0
Aug 13 17:05:25 MyApp <Error>: CGContextDrawTiledImage: invalid context 0x0
Aug 13 17:05:25 MyApp <Error>: CGContextRestoreGState: invalid context 0x0
Aug 13 17:05:25 MyApp <Error>: CGContextRestoreGState: invalid context 0x0
```

Is this a Cocoa bug or am I doing something wrong (and how to correct it if it's something I'm doing)?

Comment: What is self.backButton?

Comment: self.backButton is a UIButton defined on a storyboard.

Comment: I copied and pasted your code, and it worked fine for me. How do you know that this code is causing the errors?

Comment: Interesting! I suppose it is this code because if I change or comment that particular line, I do not see the errors -- it only occurs if I use the resizable image. Perhaps what I am doing with the view relates to the issue -- I am instantiating it from the Storyboard, then pushing it animated onto a nav stack. This nav controller is in a container view occupying a subsection of the screen. I'll try to strip away the complexity and see when it starts complaining.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably because your have set the wrong `edgeInsets`. Please make sure that your `edgeInsets.left + edgeInsets.right` is less than your `image.size.width` and `edgeInsets.top + edgeInsets.bottom` less than `image.size.height`.

Or you probably want to review [this question&answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13567266/2638425)

Comment: Ah, that may well be it (I'll try tomorrow). My top + bottom == height because I did not want it to tile vertically. FWIW, it does display correctly.