# Take image of an invisible portion of the UIWebView

Tags: ios, uiwebview, uiimage, core-graphics

I want to create uiimage s from portions of some uiwebview content.

Assume that my webview has size of (200,200). And it has a content of (800,200) in its contentview, which is scrollable,

I want to take the screenshot of the following rect CGRectMake(400,0,200,200).

I tried this:

```
CGRect rect = CGRectMake(pageIndex * webView.frame.size.width, 0, webView.frame.size.width, webView.frame.size.height);
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext([webView getScrollView].bounds.size);
CGContextRef c = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextClipToRect(c, rect);
[webView.layer renderInContext:c];
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

It works for the first page of webview, but for other pages, it does not take the image, a white colored image has created.

What could be the problem? How can I create screenshots of the **currently invisible** parts of the scrollview?

Thanks for help,

Answer (score 1):

[ScroolViewScrrenshotGitHub](https://github.com/st3fan/iphone-experiments/tree/master/Miscellaneous/ScrollViewScreenShot/)

Here [Getting a screenshot of a UIScrollView, including offscreen parts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3539717/getting-a-screenshot-of-a-uiscrollview-including-offscreen-parts)