# AirPrint the UIView Layout

Tags: ios, swift, airprint

Is it possible to print the layout of a UIView. Should I create a PDF from the contents of the view?
What is the best way of going about this?  Thanks.

Comment: Do you want to print the whole content on particular view? By print you mean to send the data and print with a printer or you want to save the view content in specific format?

Comment: I would like to AirPrint an image and the contents of a text view with a printer

Answer (score 0):

As you just want to print the content, according to me, best option would be to take screenshot of the entire view and print it ([take screenshot of view content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2214957/how-do-i-take-a-screen-shot-of-a-uiview?answertab=active#tab-top))

- If your textView is having contents off the scroll area, then it can be slightly tricky. You need to take the screen shot of entire textview (including area not visible) [checkhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3539717/getting-a-screenshot-of-a-uiscrollview-including-offscreen-parts?answertab=active#tab-top), and the image on image view separately. Then you need to combine these two in desired way.

After that you can print the image.