# Screen shot taken on iOS isn't of a whole view

Tags: ios, ipad, uitextview, screenshot

I'm trying to get an image of the contents of a UITextView, including the part that is not currently visible on the screen. I do it exactly as pointed out in the first answer here:
[Getting a screenshot of a UIScrollView, including offscreen parts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3539717/getting-a-screenshot-of-a-uiscrollview-including-offscreen-parts/3539944#3539944), except for using a UITextView instead of a UIScrollView. Unfortunately, no matter what changes I do to the code, I'm always only getting a part of my UITextView, which is about 1024x315 (I test it on the iPad simulator, in landscape orientation). Why is the size so weird and how can I make it as I want to?

That's how I'm saving the image (ResultsView is an instance of UITextView):

```
UIImage* image = nil;

UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(ResultsView.contentSize);
CGPoint savedContentOffset = ResultsView.contentOffset;
CGRect savedFrame = ResultsView.frame;

ResultsView.contentOffset = CGPointZero;
ResultsView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, ResultsView.contentSize.width, ResultsView.contentSize.height);

[ResultsView.layer renderInContext: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

ResultsView.contentOffset = savedContentOffset;
ResultsView.frame = savedFrame;
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

NSData * data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum([UIImage imageWithData:data], nil, nil, nil);
```

Comment: A ScrollView is special, in that it simulates a larger "screen" internally.  A TextView does not.

Comment: Post the code you use to create the screenshot

Comment: @HotLicks OK, I understand you, but then how can I get an image of the whole text?

Comment: Maybe make the TextView full size and then put it in a ScrollView.