# Snapshot to cover scrolled items

Tags: ios, swift

I'm developing an iOS application where a user can add as many texts and images as possible (just like typing and adding emojis on the iPhone textview) to a `UITextView`.

Is there any way to take a snapshot to cover the scrolled items. I need to post whatever the user has added into the `UITextView` to his/her Facebook wall. At the moment, the snapshot only captures what is visible on the screen. I'm using Swift.

The Code:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(message.contentSize, false, 0);
message.layer.renderInContext(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
let img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you capture your snapshot, use `(0, 0)` as the origin and the scroll view's `contentSize` as the size instead of using your scroll view's `bounds` directly. This is because `UIScrollView` (and its subclasses, like `UITextView`) shifts its `bounds` when scrolling, so the `bounds` rectangle represents only the portion of the scroll view that is visible.

**Edit:** it looks like `UITextView` might not draw the parts of itself that are outside its bounds, so you may have to temporarily adjust its frame, as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3539717/getting-a-screenshot-of-a-uiscrollview-including-offscreen-parts/3539944#3539944).

Comment: Thanks @Zev Eisenberg, I did that but I realized that the image size is that of the content but the scrolled items were lost. Below is the code

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(message.contentSize, false, 0);
    message.layer.renderInContext(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()), afterScreenUpdates: true);
    let img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

Comment: Sorry about the formatting. I'm trying to figure out how it works around here.

Comment: Best would be to edit your original post and add the code there.

Comment: Alright, thanks @Zev Eisenberg. This helps but unfortunately, I can't vote up because of limited privileges.