# Take screenshot of ViewController with scrollview

Tags: ios, swift, scrollview, screenshot

I searched SO and tried many given solutions but in vain, am developing an app in which i need to take a screenshot, i have a UIViewController and a scrollview, In the scrollview i have some labels and at the bottom of the screen i have a button, which is visible when i scroll to the bottom.

When i click the button which is at the bottom of the screen, i want to capture all of the screen from top to bottom, but the problem i am facing is, its not scrolling to the top, i am getting only the visible area of the screen in the screenshot, as seen in this image:
I am using below code, Thanks in advance

```
//Create the UIImage
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(view.bounds.size)  //view.frame.size
view.layer.renderInContext(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
sharedImage = image
```

Comment: Looking for this? http://stackoverflow.com/a/3539944/1208191

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are doing is taking the screenshot of `SuperView` which is on top of `UIViewController`. You need to take screenshot of `UIScrollView` and for that you need to pass the `contentSize` of `UIScrollView`.

```
//Create the UIImage

UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(scrollView.contentSize)  //Change this line only
view.layer.renderInContext(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
sharedImage = image
```

Now you will get the screenshot of complete `UIScrollView`.

Comment: This almost works but when there is a NavigationBar it chops off the top.. any thoughts??

Comment: Can you post screenshot of your `UIViewController`?