# How to Take a Full Screenshot on iOS Simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator

When developing apps that have `ScrollView` content that is larger than the screen, is there a way to capture a "full screenshot" of the entire screen.

Currently, the screenshot option in File > Save Screen Shot `⌘ + S` only saves a screenshot of the current screen view.

Ideally, I would like to take a full screenshot of the entire scrollable view without having to manually stitch together the separate screenshots.

Comment: This is answered here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3539717/getting-a-screenshot-of-a-uiscrollview-including-offscreen-parts

Comment: @RaunakJoneja This has been done in code. I was ideally looking for a solution that could be run for any app, without modifying the source code. Do you know of any such solution?

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to take screenshot of full scrolling screen. Normally Just Click on Simulator and Press ⌘ + S Button to take screenshot.

Comment: This is not working in xcode9 simulator.