# Take screenshots programmatically of entire scrollable area of another app in iOS

Tags: ios, screenshot, ios-app-extension, custom-keyboard

Currently it is cumbersome for the user to repeatedly scroll and take a screenshot if they want to capture more than what can fit on the screen at a time.

I would like to implement functionality such that at the request of a user (e.g. via tapping a special button on a custom keyboard), screenshots of the entire scrollable area of the currently opened app are automatically taken and stitched together.

Is this possible? And if so, how?

To clarify, **the application containing the scrollable area is a third party application over which I have no control**, e.g. iMessage or Facebook.

Edit: I am aware of answers like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3539717/getting-a-screenshot-of-a-uiscrollview-including-offscreen-parts) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4334233/how-to-capture-uiview-to-uiimage-without-loss-of-quality-on-retina-display) that are about taking screenshots within an app that I control. As far as I can tell, these are not applicable in my situation. Please correct me if I am wrong about this.

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible. Each app is contained in a protected sandbox that no other apps have access to.

You could make a custom keyboard, but you still wouldn't have access to any of the views in the app that you don't control.