# How to extract images from a PDF files

Tags: swift, image, macos, pdf

To gain time and efforts, I want to scan questionnaires (several pages each) into a PDF file and then extract as an image each page and watermark it. I did most of the code in Swift already but cannot figure out how to do the first step (i.e. extract images).

Thank you in advance

Comment: Have you checked this link? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3539717/getting-a-screenshot-of-a-uiscrollview-including-offscreen-parts

Comment: Do you want to extract the images in the pdf file or do you want to convert each page in the pdf file to an image? Did you try anything?

Comment: I want to extract each page as an image (JPEG) to further apply line detection, watermarking and mark recognition.

Comment: To date, I have been able to code the line detection and watermarking on a JPEG image.

Comment: You can use the tool `pdfimages` to extract images from a PDF. It is in the Poppler tools package which you can install on a Mac using **homebrew**, i.e. `brew install poppler`

Comment: Take a look at [PDFKit](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/pdfkit) and [PDF Document Parsing](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_pdf_scan/dq_pdf_scan.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001066-CH220-TPXREF101).

Answer (score 0):

When you scan a document the software has a box to select how to save the scan, You can just select the image option and each page will be saved as a separate image. In System Preferences/Printers and Scanners. you have 3 choices to save the scan: TIFF, PNG, or PDF. Be sure to select one of the image options. This will scan each page as a separate image.

Comment: Yes jmh I know that but I have thousands of pages to scan ans following your advice I would have to rename each file. I tried to group rename in MacOS which helped a bit.