# Getting a full screenshot of a UIScrollView in iOS 13

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, scrollview, core-graphics

I am using **Swift 5** and **iOS 13**. I am trying to take a screenshot of the entire scrollview image and print it, but the bottom appears in white. How can i solve this problem? I showed and explained everything in the picture below.

I am also checked [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3539717/getting-a-screenshot-of-a-uiscrollview-including-offscreen-parts)

[image]

My extension code like this:

```
extension UIScrollView {

    func screenshot() -> UIImage {

        let savedContentOffset = contentOffset
        let savedFrame = frame

        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(contentSize, false, 0)

        contentOffset = .zero
        frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: contentSize.width, height: contentSize.height)
        layer.render(in: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
        let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

        contentOffset = savedContentOffset
        frame = savedFrame

        return image ?? UIImage()

    }

}
```

Comment: Check the topic again that you linked - it has answers how to fix the issue for iOS 13 - cloning scroll view with keyed archiver or removing it from parent. Why it happens - I believe due to autolayout and existing constraints.

Comment: Are you using a table view or collection view? Both of them are subclass of scroll view. And both of them are designed to not draw content that is not visible on the screen.

Comment: @MaticOblak Yes, I have collectionView in my scrollView.

Comment: @Mikhail I look it and can't find answer in Swift. Can you write the solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's seems like iOS 13 bug but I found the solution in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58594935/7825024) answer.

The solution is I am **removing scrollview from superview** and then *adding in with its old constraints after taking the screenshot*. Yeah, it's stupid but it just works that way :(

```
scrollView.removeFromSuperview()
let print = scrollView.screenshot()
mainView.addSubview(scrollView)
scrollView.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
    make.top.equalTo(topView.snp.bottom)
    make.left.bottom.right.equalToSuperview()
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Here is the code snippet that worked for me.

```
extension UIView {
    
    func snapshot(scrollView: UIScrollView) -> UIImage? {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(scrollView.contentSize, false, UIScreen.main.scale)
        layer.render(in: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
        let savedContentOffset = scrollView.contentOffset
        let savedFrame = frame
        
        scrollView.contentOffset = CGPoint.zero
        frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: scrollView.contentSize.width, height: scrollView.contentSize.height)
        
        layer.render(in: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
        let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        
        scrollView.contentOffset = savedContentOffset
        frame = savedFrame
        
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        
        return image
    }
}
```

And when you call it:

```
view.snapshot(scrollView: scrollView)
```

Comment: yea, that works :)