# iOS: Programmatically capture screenshot of view larger than screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I would like to take a screenshot of an entire UICollectionView (or at least the "top 10" cells). The view doesn't fit on screen.

How do I programmatically capture a snapshot of a view larger than the iPhone's screen?

Answer (score 0):

The problem of capturing a scroll view's content including the offscreen part has been tackled here many times before, so please, search before asking. (See for example: [Getting a screenshot of a UIScrollView, including offscreen parts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3539717/getting-a-screenshot-of-a-uiscrollview-including-offscreen-parts.))

But even that won't help you here, because in particular, a collection view's cells that are not shown on the screen *do not even exist;* that is what cell reuse is about. So there is in fact nothing in existence to take a screen shot *of*. The cells you can see are the only cells there are.

To put it another way; the collection view *does* fit on the screen. What's on the screen *is* the collection view. There isn't any more of it.

You could perhaps construct in code a drawing that looks somewhat like your collection view, but it could be quite a bit of work.